# SQL query taking too long - help for better performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am running a stored procedure in which i have the following query

```
SELECT TOP 1 @TopValue = t2.myDecimal

from table1 t1, table2 t2

where t1.ID = t2.table1ID

and CONVERT( VARCHART(8), t1.Created, 112 ) = @stringYYYYMMDD

and t1.Term = @Label"
```

TopRate is Decimal(8,6)
stringYYYYMMDD is a string representing a date in the format YYYYMMDD
Label is a simple varchar(8)

This query is called for every row of my data set, that can be from 10 to 5000. If I comment this query, the procedure execution time is under 2 seconds. With the query included, it just never ends.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server management studio 2008 R2

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 5):

First, you should use explicit `join` syntax.  Second, it is suspicious whenever you have a `top` without an `order by`.  So, your query as I see it is:

```
select TOP 1 @TopValue = t2.myDecimal
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.ID = t2.table1ID
where CONVERT( VARCHART(8), t1.Created, 112 ) = @stringYYYYMMDD and t1.Term = @Label"
```

You can speed this up with some indexes.  But, before doing that, you want to change the date comparison:

```
where t1.Created >= convert(datetime, @stringYYYYMMDD, 112) and
      t1.Created < convert(datetime, @stringYYYYMMDD, 112) + 1 and
      t1.Term = @Label
```

Moving the function from the column to the constant makes the comparison "sargable", meaning that indexes can be used for it.

Next, create the indexes `table1(Term, Created, Id)` and `table2(table1Id)`.  These indexes should boost performance.

Comment: +1. The t1 comparisn as string is a typical beginner mistake - it takes out any chance to use an index.

Comment: First time I tried your solution it worked fine but it was because  I forgot to type '+ 1' in t1.Created < convert(datetime, @stringYYYYMMDD, 112) + 1 so no entries were found. With the correct solution, my query is still taking a long time. I also created the indexes but this did not change to much the execution time.

Comment: What is the data type of `Created`?

Comment: it is a datetime type

Comment: @Greg . . . You have created a composite index on table1 with three columns, in the order specified in the answer?

Comment: Yes. I executed the following statement: CREATE INDEX myIndex
ON table1(Term, Created, Id). I spent some times trying to re think all the procedure. Instead of a query to find the top values matching my parameters in table1 and table2 which is over a million a row, I create a table a the beginning of the whole procedure only with the top values. It seems to make it but I can't figure why the described query failed... I still have the script to test any idea

Comment: @Greg . . . Check that `select convert(datetime, @stringYYYYMMDD, 112), convert(datetime, @stringYYYYMMDD, 112) + 1` return what you expect.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Let's say '@stringYYYYMMDD = '20100301', this query returns 2010-03-01 00:00:00.000  -  2010-03-02 00:00:00.000'. Then this result is compared to 't1.created' which is for example: '2005-09-21 21:00:02.020'

Comment: Do you have an index on `table2(table1id)`?

Comment: Yes I did this part too.